# Crash when opening binary table with column widths in Astropy

Tags: python, astropy, fits

I want to open a binary table held in a FITS file. I am using Python, but I have also tried fv and SAOImageDS9.

```
from astropy.io import fits
f=fits.open('ioa_pmotion.fits')
f.info() #this shows that the binary table is in extension 1
f[0].data #this responds with "None" because the primary (extension 0) is empty
f[1].data #here is where the error occurs
g=f[1].data
print(g[0]) #this should show the first row of the table
```

The error that occurs from the fifth line is, "signed integer is greater than maximum."

From line 3, I am told that the table has 1 row and 18 columns but that it also has over 8 GB. I am trying to access these 8 GB of data, but I am not sure how to get to them. I have received the titles of each of the 18 columns, and they are the names of the types of data I am trying to retrieve (object ID, proper motion values, extinction values, etc.), so I am wondering if the data is somehow stored in these columns.

[Column names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDPm1.png)

[Full traceback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vm4jO.png)

Comment: Are you on a 32-bit system? Or using 32-bit Python on a 64-bit system? The Astropy documentation at http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/io/fits/index.html suggests you will need a 64-bit environment to read a file larger than 2-3 Gb.

Comment: I am using 64-bit Python on a 64-bit system.

Comment: Could you show the full traceback, so we can see the relevant astropy source code as well?

Comment: Is that (the attached image above) what you mean? Also, thank you both for responding!

Comment: What is your python version?

Comment: 2.7.11, but I also tried it on 3.6.1 with the same result.

Comment: ok and your numpy version?

Comment: numpy is 1.11.3-2

Comment: Can you try to update it to 1.13.0 and see what happens? Just a hunch. Not sure that it will work

Comment: I got it up to 1.12 in Spyder with the same result, and it says that is the latest update (and Spyder is at its latest update as well).

Comment: This is not a normal binary table.  I've seen this kind of format before.  It's a hack that's used sometimes to made a binary table column-oriented in memory rather than row-oriented, by having a single row containing columns that each are huge arrays.  Unfortunately this looks like something of a bug in Numpy.  It's using a 32-bit signed int for the field offsets and they overflow.

Comment: I feel like I've seen this come up before, but I don't remember if or where the issue was recorded.

Comment: Ah, this is the existing Astropy issue (from 2013!): https://github.com/astropy/astropy/issues/1840  I don't think I ever submitted an issue about this to Numpy though.

Comment: Really what Numpy should do is change `PyArray_ArrayDescr.elsize` to a `size_t` maybe.  There's no good reason for it to ever be negative, and right now it's just a plain `int` too, so limited to 2GB.  But that's a big, very pervasive change.

Comment: Thanks for the link! That led me to find this, http://www.star.bristol.ac.uk/~mbt/papers/adassXVII-P4-6-poster.pdf, and I was able to open the table using TOPCAT.

Comment: Please don't link to images of code: copy-paste the column names and traceback into your question.